# CSS Column-count on chrome not working the right way

Tags: css, google-chrome

Have some bug on chrome. (with column-count 1 or 2 it's ok but 3, 4, 5 and so on not working)

```
.minmin-masonry-content {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1.5rem;
    column-gap: 1.5rem;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

I search alot, but nothing helped.

```
-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Example here: [DEMO](http://zex.mgstudio.lt/) it's first with filters. Maybe someone have same problems?

**AND PLEASE DON'T WRITE TO USE PLUGINS.**

Answer (score -1):

Would you consider using Flex instead?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container div {
  flex-basis: 19%;
  margin: 0.5%;
}

.container div img {
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div> 
  <img src="//www.fillmurray.com/300/400" width="100%">
 </div>
 
 <div> 
  <img src="//www.fillmurray.com/300/400" width="100%">
 </div>
 
 <div> 
  <img src="//www.fillmurray.com/300/400" width="100%">
 </div>
 
 <div> 
  <img src="//www.fillmurray.com/300/400" width="100%">
 </div>
 
 <div> 
  <img src="//www.fillmurray.com/300/400" width="100%">
 </div>
 
  
 <div> 
  <img src="//www.fillmurray.com/300/400" width="100%">
 </div>
 
  
 <div> 
  <img src="//www.fillmurray.com/300/400" width="100%">
 </div>
 
</div>
```

Comment: attribute `width` , that's so 90's

Comment: no I don't need flexbox. I need to solve this problem with column-count.